# Trying to Get Titles Capitalized

Tags: javascript, formatting, prototype, ejs

This is my JavaScript that I borrowed from someone:

```
String.prototype.toTitleCase = function() {
  var i, j, str, lowers, uppers;
  str = this.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s-]*) */g, function(txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });

  // Certain minor words should be left lowercase unless 
  // they are the first or last words in the string
  lowers = ['A', 'An', 'The', 'And', 'But', 'Or', 'For', 'Nor', 'As', 'At', 
  'By', 'For', 'From', 'In', 'Into', 'Near', 'Of', 'On', 'Onto', 'To', 'With'];
  for (i = 0, j = lowers.length; i < j; i++)
    str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\s' + lowers[i] + '\\s', 'g'), 
      function(txt) {
        return txt.toLowerCase();
      });

  // Certain words such as initialisms or acronyms should be left uppercase
  uppers = ['Id', 'Tv'];
  for (i = 0, j = uppers.length; i < j; i++)
    str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + uppers[i] + '\\b', 'g'), 
      uppers[i].toUpperCase());

  return str;
};
```

For some reason, I can't get this code to work in my ejs file...This is a portion of my code there.

```
<h3 class="lead campground-name2 thumbnail text-center"><%= campground.name.toTitleCase(); %></h3>
```

This is the error I get when I call it:

```
TypeError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v12/views/campgrounds/show.ejs:6
   4|         <div class='row'>
   5|             <div class="col-md-3">
>> 6|                 <h3 class="lead campground-name2 thumbnail text-center"><%= campground.name.toTitleCase(); %></h3>
   7|                 <div class="list-group">
   8|                     <a href="#description" class="list-group-item active active-first text-center">Description</a>
   9|                     <a href="#comments" class="list-group-item active text-center">Comments</a>

campground.name.toTitleCase is not a function
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v12/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:481:12), <anonymous>:52:40)
   at returnedFn (/home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v12/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:512:17)
   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v12/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:364:31)
   at View.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v12/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
   at tryRender (/home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v12/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
   at EventEmitter.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v12/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
   at ServerResponse.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v12/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960:7)
   at /home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v12/routes/campgrounds.js:64:17
   at /home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v12/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2313:18
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
```

I know it is linked correctly because I have other functions in this file that are working on this page already. Am I calling this method incorrectly? It looks as though it should be called like .toUpperCase, which I've tested and works with this code...Any help would be amazing. Thank you all in advance!

Here is the entirety of my EJS file. The file is linked in the footer, which I can post if you need. The code is on lines 6 and 50 if that helps at all...

```
<% include ../partials/header %>
<body class="blue">
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3 class="lead campground-name2 thumbnail text-center"><%= campground.name.toTitleCase(); %></h3>
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#description" class="list-group-item active active-first text-center">Description</a>
                    <a href="#comments" class="list-group-item active text-center">Comments</a>
                </div>

                <!--RATINGS-->
                <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-ratings">
                    <form class="center-ratings" action="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/ratings" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="rating">Leave a rating:</label>
                            <fieldset class="starability-basic form-group center-ratings" id="rating">
                              <input type="radio" id="first-rate5" name="rating[rating]" value="5" />
                              <label for="first-rate5" title="Amazing">5 stars</label>
                              <input type="radio" id="first-rate4" name="rating[rating]" value="4" />
                              <label for="first-rate4" title="Very good">4 stars</label>
                              <input type="radio" id="first-rate3" name="rating[rating]" value="3" />
                              <label for="first-rate3" title="Average">3 stars</label>
                              <input type="radio" id="first-rate2" name="rating[rating]" value="2" />
                              <label for="first-rate2" title="Not good">2 stars</label>
                              <input type="radio" id="first-rate1" name="rating[rating]" value="1" />
                              <label for="first-rate1" title="Terrible">1 star</label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-success">
                                Submit rating!
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="center-ratings">
                        Current Rating: <%= campground.rating.toFixed(2) %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--SHOW Image, price, description, comments-->
            <div class='col-md-9 pull-right'>
                <div class='thumbnail'>
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= campground.image %>"> <!--IMAGE-->
                    </div>
                    <div class='caption-full' id="description">
                        <h3 class="pull-right price">$<%= campground.price.toFixed(2) %>/night</h3> <!--PRICE-->
                        <h3 class="campground-name"><%= campground.name.toTitleCase(); %></h3>
                        <pre><%= campground.description %></pre>
                        <!--shows who submitted campground-->
                        <p><span><em>Submitted <%= moment(campground.createdAt).fromNow() %> by <%= campground.author.username %></em></span></p>

                        <!--EDIT/DELETE CAMPGROUND BUTTONS-->
                        <% if(currentUser && campground.author.id.equals(currentUser._id)){ %>
                            <a class='btn btn-sm btn-warning btn-below' href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/edit">Edit</a>
                            <form id="delete-form" action='/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>?_method=DELETE' method='POST'>
                                <button class='btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-below'>Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        <% } %>

                        <!--COMMENTS-->
                        <% if(currentUser && campground.comments.length === 0){ %> <!--if no comments, create button at bottom of description-->
                            <div class="text-right comment-0">
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/comments/new">Add a comment</a> 
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                        <% } %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <% if(campground.comments.length > 0) { %> <!--if no comments, hide gray box-->
                <div class='well' id="comments">    
                    <!--comass="text-right"-->
                    <% campground.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
                        <div class="row comment-name">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="comment-username">
                                    <strong><%= comment.author.username %></strong>
                                    <!--Make this accurate. Currently always set to 10 days-->
                                    <span class='pull-right'><em><%= moment(comment.createdAt).fromNow() %></em></span>
                                </div>
                                <pre><%= comment.text %></pre>
                                <% if(currentUser && comment.author.id.equals(currentUser._id)){ %>
                                <a class='btn btn-xs btn-warning' href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/comments/<%= comment._id %>/edit">Edit</a>
                                <form id="delete-form" action='/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/comments/<%= comment._id %>?_method=DELETE' method='POST'>
                                    <button class='btn btn-xs btn-danger'>Delete</button>
                                </form>
                                <% } %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    <% }) %>
                    <% if(currentUser){ %>
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/comments/new">Add a comment</a>
                        </div>
                    <% } %>
                </div>
                <% } %>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

Comment: I ran your function and it works fine. Is your script tag above your h3 tag? Post more of your html

Comment: Where have you put the toTitleCase code? Is it on a separate file?

Comment: it looks like the "toTitleCase" is in another scope and therefore #ejs does not recognize it

Comment: The toTitleCase is in a separate file. The file is linked correctly - there is other JS in the same file that is running perfectly on the same page. I will edit the post above to show more of my ejs.

Bruno BG - I'm not sure what you mean by scope in this case...I'm somewhat new, if you can't tell by this issue, but from what I understand of scope, I think everything is done correctly...Could you please explain a little more? I apologize, I'm mostly self-taught and some of this goes a little above my head yet.

Thank you all for your quick responses!!